# Possible error in long, complicated sentence?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

I am reading a book and which contains this sentence.

> Industrial designers will usually take in a lightly defined scope, including the features, use cases, and target markets make sense for your product—including any known sizes or volumes that need to be accommodated for functionality—and will then determine what the product should look and feel like.

I can't understand what *and target markets make sense for your product*. Is it an independent sentence there, or does it need an *-ing* or *that*?

> Industrial designers will usually take in a lightly defined scope, including the features, use cases, and target markets **that** make sense for your product […].

Can anyone tell me the meaning in a simpler way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question asks for an explanation of an ungrammatical construction.

Comment: When you quote a source, you should cite it. If possible you can link to it. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) Presumably the work to be cited is this or another edition of the book: *The Hardware Startup: Building Your Product, Business, and Brand*, Renee DiResta, Brady Forrest, Ryan Vinyard (https://books.google.com/books?id=EI2rCQAAQBAJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s almost certainly an error in what was written. Your two suggested fixes would both work:

- and target markets that make sense for your product
- and target markets making sense for your product

The word *target* there is a noun describing *markets*; it’s not a verb whose object is *markets*, although this isn’t easy to make out quickly.